# yarn test fails with jasmine-ts yargs dependency

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, yargs, jasmine-ts

I am running `yarn test` to run my tests. I had to update some versions in my `package.json` file beforehand, so I deleted the `yarn.lock` file. Before removing the `yarn.lock` file, the tests pass just fine. Now, the tests fail with this error:

```
TypeError: shim$1.Parser.looksLikeNumber is not a function
    at Object.Yargs.self._parsePositionalNumbers (/Users/me/dev/test-app/node_modules/jasmine-ts/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:2804:31)
```

My `package.json` includes:

```
"jasmine-ts": "^0.3.0"
```

The old `yarn.lock` file looked like this:

```
jasmine-ts@^0.3.0:
  version: "0.3.0"
  resolved: (...)
  integrity: (...)
  dependencies:
    yargs: "^8.0.2"
```

The new `yarn.lock` file looks like this:

```
jasmine-ts@^0.3.0:
  version "0.3.3"
  resolved: (...)
  integrity: (...)
  dependencies:
    yargs "^16.2.0"
```

I believe that the version of `yargs` that `jasmine-ts` is showing should not be giving me this error. Is there a way for me to fix this or is this a bug in `jasmine-ts`? The latest version is `0.4.0`, which also gives the same error on test, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue but `yargs` in my case was a sub-dependency of `jest-cli`

Found your question while I was looking for a clue on this and thanks to your version pointers, I was able to resolve this.

I added `yargs` version `13.3.2` to **resolutions** and it fixed the issue.

package.json

```
"resolutions": {

   "yargs": "^13.3.2"

}
```

`yargs` could be a sub-dependency of some other module as well in your project, If you know of a version that worked fine, add that to resolutions. Else, go with `13.3.2` since it doesn't throw this `TypeError: shim$1.Parser.looksLikeNumber is not a function`.

**Note**:- You're not removing the previous version, resolutions will just pin your sub-dependency to the specified version.

**Good Read on Resolutions**:- https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/understanding-npm-dependency-resolution-84a24180901b